# How to validate an input url to allow only url ending in .gif and urls that contains "youtube"

Tags: html, input

I have 2 input type=url, one for submit a gif and the other to submit a Youtube video.

I want to filter this inputs with pattern atributte. My idea is filter like this:
 - Gif url -> only allows urls ending in .gif
 - Youtube url -> only allows urls that contains "youtube" word.

Now, i have this

```html
<input type="url" placeholder="URL Gif" pattern="(.gif)" />
<input type="url" placeholder="URL Youtube" pattern="+youtube+" />
```

This is not working for me.
(PD: sorry my bad english)

PD2: Finally I found a solution for youtube urls, but still not for gif urls.

**SOLUTION FOR FILTER INPUT YOUTUBE URL**

```html
<input type="url" pattern="http://www\.youtube\.com\/(.+)|https://www\.youtube\.com\/(.+)" />
```

Comment: "+" means "more than once" and not concatenation.

Comment: @Psytho thanks for your answer. I didn't know that. How can I do then?